# Higher order central moments for uncorrelated random variables

Tags: correlation, moments

Two random variables (RVs) $x$ and $y$ are uncorrelated, which implies that $\mathbb{E}[xy]=\mathbb{E}[x]\mathbb{E}[y]$. Let the zero-mean deviation variable be marked with a tilde, e.g. $\tilde{x}=x-\mathbb{E}[x]$.

The second central moment is calculated as $\mathbb{E}[\tilde{x}\tilde{y}]=\mathbb{E}[\tilde{x}]\mathbb{E}[\tilde{y}]$.

Does this hold for higher-order central moments? That is, is
$\mathbb{E}[\tilde{x}^{i}\tilde{y}^{i}]=\mathbb{E}[\tilde{x}^{i}]\mathbb{E}[\tilde{y}^{i}]$?

Comment: Please define what the non-standard notation $E(x,y)$ means.

Comment: @utobi I think he probably meant $E[xy]$ (the expectation of the product of $x$ and $y$).

Comment: Your question is unclear: what exactly do you mean by "$\mathbb{E}[\tilde{x}^{i},\tilde{y}^{i}]$" and why would that be that any different from $\mathbb{E}[X,Y]$ with $X=\tilde{x}^i$ and $Y=\tilde{y}^i$, which is covered by your first two paragraphs?

Comment: Re the edit: your claim about how "the first central moment" is computed is incorrect.  That equation of expectations instead expresses that the *covariance* (a *second* central moment) is zero.

Comment: Yes, there was an error in my question, I was indeed meaning $\mathbb{E}[xy]$. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is

> *If $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, does
> $$E[(X - E[X])^i(Y - E[Y])^i] = E[(X - E[X])^i]E[(Y - E[Y])^i]$$
> hold for $i \geq 2$?*

then the answer is a clear NO.

A simple counterexample is as follows: let $X \sim U(-1, 1)$, $Y = X^2$ (this is also a common example to demonstrate uncorrelated r.v.s do not have to be independent), then $E[X] = 0$, $E[Y] = 2\int_0^1 x^2 \frac{1}{2}dx = \frac{1}{3}$, and $E[XY] = E[X^3] = 0$, i.e., $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.  For $i = 2$, we have
\begin{align*}
& E[(X - E[X])^2] = \frac{1}{3}, \\
& E[(Y - E(Y))^2] = E\left[\left(X^2 - \frac{1}{3}\right)^2\right] = 
\int_0^1(x^2 - 2/3)^2dx = \frac{1}{5}, \\
& E[(X - E(X))^2(Y - E[Y])^2] = E\left[X^2\left(X^2 - \frac{2}{3}\right)^2\right] = 
\int_0^1x^2(x^2 - 2/3)^2dx = \frac{23}{945}.
\end{align*}

Clearly $E[(X - E[X])^2(Y - E[Y])^2] \neq E[(X - E[X])^2]E[(Y - E[Y])^2]$.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, though I think there are some errors in your calculations of expectation values. From the definition of expectation values: $\mathbb{E}[g(x)]=\int g(x)f(x)dx$ where $f(x)$ is the pdf of $x$. So in your example I get e.g. $\mathbb{E}[y]=\mathbb{E}[x^2]=\int_{-1}^1 x^2 \frac{1}{1-(-1)}dx=\int_0^1 x^2dx=1/3$. Nevertheless, I think your conclusion is correct and thanks for the nice example.

Comment: @kampfkoloss Thanks for pointing it out, I will correct it.